# How can I set default values using Getopt::Std?

Tags: perl, getopt

I am trying to collect the values from command line using [Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) in my Perl script.

```
use Getopt::Std;
$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;
getopts('i:o:p:');
my $inputfile = our $opt_i;
my $outputfile = our $opt_o;
my $parameter_value = our $opt_p;
```

Here the first two variables ($inputfile,$outputfile) are mandatory but the last variable ($parameter_value) is optional and can be ignored.

I am trying to set some value by default to the last variable ($parameter_value) when the `-p` flag is ignored at the command line.

I tried using this:

```
my $parameter_value = our $opt_p || "20";
```

Here its passes the correct value when -p flag is ignored at command line. But the problem is when I am providing some value from the command line (for instance -p 58), the same value 20 is passed to the program instead of 58 which I passed from command line.

Can you please help me out by pointing the mistakes I am making here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Std;

getopts('i:o:p:');
our($opt_i, $opt_o, $opt_p);

my $inputfile = $opt_i;
my $outputfile = $opt_o;
my $parameter_value = $opt_p || "20";

print "$_\n" for $inputfile, $outputfile, $parameter_value;
```

```
C:\Temp> ks -iinput -ooutput -p55
input
output
55
```

```
C:\Temp> ks -iinput -ooutput
input
output
20
```

Comment: thanx Sinan, This works very much fine and retains the format of my coding. Thanx a ton.

Comment: If you're using 5.10+ it would be better to use `//` instead of `||` because the latter tests for truth, not defined-ness. It will prevent you from being able to pass in false values (e.g. 0). The long-winded way to get equivalent behavior prior to 5.10 is `$x = defined $y ? $y : Z` where `Z` is the default value.

Comment: @Michael Carman I guess I assumed that 0 was not a valid value.

Comment: So, I take it there was some problem with using `our` within the assignment statement itself, and using it beforehand fixes it? Could you expand on what the difference is between your code and Suren's?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy In terms of posted code, the placement of `our` would not make a difference. All I can deduce is that there is something else going on in his `strict`-free, `warnings`-free code which caused the latter `our` to be within the scope of a different package than the one set by `getopts`.

Answer (score 18):

The best thing is to use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and use a hash instead of individual variables.
Then you can pass default values by pre-populating the array

```
    use Getopt::Long;
    my %opts = (parameter => 20);
    GetOptions( \%opts, 
            'p|parameter=i', 
            'o|outputfile=s',
            'i|inputfile=s'
    ) or die "Invalid parameters!";

    # I didn't bother cloning STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting the opt variables to defaults prior to calling getopts. Additionally, you can then use the $opt_ variables in your usage message to show the default values.

```
use Getopt::Std;
$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;
our $opt_p = 20;
sub HELP_MESSAGE { print " -p  parameter value (default $opt_p)\n"; }
getopts('i:o:p:');
my $inputfile = our $opt_i;
my $outputfile = our $opt_o;
my $parameter_value = our $opt_p;
```

Comment: Or just use `$opt_i` whenever you need it. Then it's clear it's a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;

my %opts = ();
getopts('i:o:p:', \%opts);
my $inputfile = $opts{i};
my $outputfile = $opts{o};
my $parameter_value = $opts{p} || "20";
print "$inputfile, $outputfile, $parameter_value\n";
```